# Adding underwater shadow to 2D top down boat

Tags: unity, 2d, sprites, mesh, masking

I have a boat/hovercraft sprite in my game. It's topdown 2D view, but it's actually a 3D scene, for better lighting and other effects. 
I want to add a buoyancy effect, so that the hovercraft floats with the waves and has a little margin for going under water, like a real boat. So when idle or when going off a ramp, when landing in the water it will kinda "bounce" a bit under and then back up. 
But the problem is: the water and boat sprites are on top of each other (because it's 2D). See this picture:
[image]

So it can not go underwater, because then the water will be on top. But I still want those edges of the vehicle to be a bit darker as it floats. I already have an effect that changes the Y value to make it float up and down. But now the edges have to become a bit darker to show they go underwater.

I kinda have this idea to add a 3D capsule and make it move up and down through the sprite to simulate this:
[image]

So as the boat and the capsule go down with each wave, it could mask the sprite, and the visible part (marked with black lines in the image below) could be made darker. To simulate the "under water" effect. Later I will also add foam and stuff, but the first problem is the underwater part. So how could I mask my sprite inside this capsule, and more importantly, make the "outsides" (so the parts of the sprite *not touching the capsule* darker? Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)
[image]